# Specify which range input to be effected by which text input and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up a page with a range, I want it to be "linked" to a number input box. These both change the font size of a div. So, as either the range slider or the number input are changed, the other is changed to match and the font size increases/decreases.

This all works when there is only one instance on the page. When I add 2, it doesn't know what is supposed to match. At the moment, both range sliders change the 2nd number box but neither change the first number box.

How do I specify in the function changeRangeValue WHICH range and changeInputValue WHICH input to change? Thank you in advance!

```js
$('#sliderA').on('input', function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('#textA').css('font-size', v + 'px')
  $('#numericA').html(v);
});

function showValue1(newValue) {
  document.getElementById("numericA").innerHTML = newValue;
}

function changeRangeValue(val) {
  document.getElementById("sliderA").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
  showValue1(val);
}

function changeInputValue(val) {
  document.getElementById("numericA").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
  showValue1(val);
}

$('#sliderB').on('input', function() {
  var v = $(this).val();
  $('#textB').css('font-size', v + 'px')
  $('#numericB').html(v);
});

function showValue1(newValue) {
  document.getElementById("numericB").innerHTML = newValue;
}

function changeRangeValue(val) {
  document.getElementById("sliderB").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
  showValue1(val);
}

function changeInputValue(val) {
  document.getElementById("numericB").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
  showValue1(val);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <span>Size:</span>
  <input type="number" id="numericA" value="16" min="10" max="40" onkeyup="changeRangeValue(this.value)" /><span> px</span>
  <input type="range" id="sliderA" value="16" min="10" max="40" oninput="changeInputValue(this.value)" /></div>
</div>
<div id="textA">To be changed by first range slider/number box. </div>
<div> <span>Size:</span>
  <input type="number" id="numericB" value="16" min="10" max="40" onkeyup="changeRangeValue(this.value)" /><span> px</span>
  <input type="range" id="sliderB" value="16" min="10" max="40" oninput="changeInputValue(this.value)" /></div>
</div>
<div id="textB">To be changed by second range slider/number box.</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your functions repeated with the same name twice.

You are also updating the font-size only when the slider value changes, I changed the code to update the font-size on the input as well.

Like so:

```js
function updateA(){
   var v = $('#sliderA').val();
   $('#textA').css('font-size', v + 'px')
}

function showValue1(newValue) {
  document.getElementById("numericA").innerHTML = newValue;
}

function changeRangeValueA(val) {
  document.getElementById("sliderA").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
  showValue1(val);
  updateA();
}

function changeInputValueA(val) {
  document.getElementById("numericA").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
  showValue1(val);
  updateA();
}

function updateB(){
   var v = $('#sliderB').val();
   $('#textB').css('font-size', v + 'px')
}

function showValue2(newValue) {
  document.getElementById("numericB").innerHTML = newValue;
}

function changeRangeValueB(val) {
  document.getElementById("sliderB").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
  showValue2(val);
  updateB();
}

function changeInputValueB(val) {
  document.getElementById("numericB").value = isNaN(parseInt(val, 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(val, 10);
  showValue2(val);
  updateB();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <span>Size:</span>
  <input type="number" id="numericA" value="16" min="10" max="40" onkeyup="changeRangeValueA(this.value)" /><span> px</span>
  <input type="range" id="sliderA" value="16" min="10" max="40" oninput="changeInputValueA(this.value)" /></div>
</div>
<div id="textA">To be changed by first range slider/number box. </div>
<div> <span>Size:</span>
  <input type="number" id="numericB" value="16" min="10" max="40" onkeyup="changeRangeValueB(this.value)" /><span> px</span>
  <input type="range" id="sliderB" value="16" min="10" max="40" oninput="changeInputValueB(this.value)" /></div>
</div>
<div id="textB">To be changed by second range slider/number box.</div>
```